# Informix - IF Statement

Tags: informix

I have the following statement for a MySQL DB.

```
if(cms_hagent.ti_availtime > '0',1,0) as "Total Available Time"
```

I need to convert it to query an Informix DB.  Any suggestions on the proper syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE` which is part of [SQL-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) standard

```sql
CASE WHEN cms_hagent.ti_availtime > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Total Available Time"
```

Answer (score 0):

On [Informix 12.10](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=block-if-elif-else-structure) and higher, you can use IF statements (in the context of SPL routines) directly with the following syntax:

```
IF [condition] THEN
[action]
ELIF [condition] THEN --optional
[action]
END IF
```

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=block-if-elif-else-structure) further states:

> The expression in an IF statement can be any valid condition, as the
> Condition segment of the IBM® Informix® Guide to SQL: Syntax
> describes. For the complete syntax and a detailed discussion of the IF
> statement, see the IBM Informix Guide to SQL: Syntax